# pandas: get elements (index, col) below diagonal in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have a pandas DataFrame, df.

I want to extract a list of all the (col, index) in the df for which the value at (col, index) > .95.

Additionally, I want to condition on the fact that they are in the lower diagonal of the df, not including the diagonal itself. (If it helps, it's a correlation df, so the diagonals are 1's which is not what I am interested in.)

How can I do this?

Comment: This is interesting - I'm curious to know the answer too. I'm aware of numpy.diagonal(), but it seems to only return the values at the diagonal, rather than the elements underneath it....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [71]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5))

In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

This masks the upper triangle (include the diagonal)

```
In [73]: mask = np.ones(df.shape,dtype='bool')

In [74]: mask[np.triu_indices(len(df))] = False

In [75]: mask
Out[75]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Simulating your condition (> 0.95)

```
In [76]: df>16
Out[76]: 
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True   True   True
4   True   True   True   True   True
```

This is prob the form you want the result

```
In [77]: df[(df>16)&mask] 
Out[77]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN  17 NaN NaN
4  20  21  22  23 NaN
```

If you really want the positional values

```
In [78]: x = ((df>16)&mask).values.nonzero()

In [79]: zip(x[0],x[1])
Out[79]: [(3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of ways you could mask out the values in the upper diagonal using `df.mask`.

One way would be to use [`np.triu`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html). This sets the values in the lower-right of an array to zero.  Here's an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3]*5, 'b': [2]*5, 'c': [1]*5, 'd': [0]*5, 'e': [6]*5})
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  3  2  1  0  6
1  3  2  1  0  6
2  3  2  1  0  6
3  3  2  1  0  6
4  3  2  1  0  6

>>> df.mask(np.triu(np.ones(df.shape, dtype=np.bool_)))
    a   b   c   d   e
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   3   2 NaN NaN NaN
3   3   2   1 NaN NaN
4   3   2   1   0 NaN
```

The following expression also produces the same DataFrame:

```
df.mask(np.arange(df.shape[0]) >= np.arange(df.shape[1])[:, np.newaxis])
```

You can then query this new DataFrame in the usual way. For example:

```
>>> dfm = df.mask(np.triu(np.ones(df.shape, dtype=np.bool_)))
>>> dfm[dfm > 1]
    a   b   c   d   e
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   3   2 NaN NaN NaN
3   3   2 NaN NaN NaN
4   3   2 NaN NaN NaN
```

To get a list of indices of your desired values, here's one option:

```
>>> a = dfm[dfm > 1]
>>> np.stack(a.notnull().values.nonzero()).T.tolist()
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1]]
```